# Selenium Opening Video on youtube & finding duration/time-elapsed

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

The following code opens an internet explorer, goes to the website youtube.com, opens a video, searches for a webelement (with id movie_player), hovers over the mouse to go to the center of webelement (ie: middle of youtube video screen so that the duration tab is visible), then tries to fetch the value of total duration and duration elapsed.

The problem seems to be that its not able to find the web element for current time as it seems the mouse hovering action does not happen as expected.

How to achieve the mouse hovering correctly?

```
WebDriver driver4 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver4.get("https://www.youtube.com");
        String[] arr = {"saiyoni saiyoni song video","bulla ki jaana main kaun video song"};
        WebDriverWait wait7 = new WebDriverWait(driver4,30);
        WebElement textBox2 = wait7.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("input[id=masthead-search-term]")));
        textBox2.sendKeys(arr[0]);
        wait7.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@id='search-btn']"))).click();
        WebElement we0 = wait7.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[@href='/watch?v=0GLYKYgSE0Y']")));
        we0.click();

Actions builder = new Actions(driver4);
        WebElement we = driver4.findElement(By.id("movie_player"));
        Action mouseMovement=builder.moveToElement(we).build();
        mouseMovement.perform();

        WebElement currentTime = wait9.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-current']")));
        WebElement durationTime= wait9.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='ytp-time-duration']")));
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[@class='ytp-time-duration'] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'
System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.1.5', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities [{acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=11, se:ieOptions={nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, elementScrollBehavior=0, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:5514/, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false}, browserName=internet explorer, pageLoadStrategy=normal, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=WINDOWS, setWindowRect=true, platform=WINDOWS}]
Session ID: 84b0b0b5-af27-4208-82bb-599d9ffa2552
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:231)
    at packageFF.browserAutomation.main(browserAutomation.java:116)
```

Comment: Can you increase webdriver wait n then try

Comment: Hi Ankur,thanks you for your recommendation,however, Increasing the webdriver wait doesn't solve the problem, still can't automate the mouse hovering functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-lightbox");
    WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Open a Div in Lightbox')]"));
    element.click();
    System.out.println("found element and clicked");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
WebElement frameElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[@src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/wswxQ3mhwqQ']"));
driver.switchTo().frame(frameElement);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@aria-label=\'Play\']")).click();
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.className("ytp-progress-bar-container"));
        Action mouseMovement=builder.moveToElement(we).build();
        mouseMovement.perform();
        we.click();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement titleText=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.className("ytp-title-link")));
        System.out.println(titleText.getText());
        WebElement time=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("span.ytp-time-current")));
        System.out.println(time.getText());
```

Comment: Above code will open a youtube video in a frame and will play that video . Using action class and moveToElement method , can move to the middle. We can display time using an element.